# Pop() function that crashes

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to implement a stack with linked lists. I am having problems with the `pop()` function. It compiles OK, but when I try to run the code it crashes on `tmp=tmp->head;` and I have no idea why. I tried google but didn't find the answer. Here is the full code:

```
struct node{ //kreiram stog

    struct node* head;
    struct node* next;
    int broj;

}node;

void push_onto(int broj){ // dodajem na glavu

    struct node* novi;
    novi=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //novi=novi->head;
    if (novi== NULL)
        printf("Smth is wrong,Jose!\n");

    else

        novi->broj=broj;
        novi->next=novi->head;
        novi->head=novi;
}

int pop()// skidam sa stoga
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp=temp->head;
    int br;
    if (temp->next==NULL)
        return -1;
        else

        br=temp->head;
        temp=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return br;

}

void top(){ //koji je element na stogu

    struct node* tmp;
    printf("Trenutni element na stogu je %d",tmp->broj);

}


void is_empty(){

    struct node* tmp;
    tmp=tmp->head;
    if (tmp->head ==NULL)
        printf("List is empty!\n");
}


void print_elem(){

    struct node* tmp;
    tmp=tmp->head;
    if (tmp->head==NULL)
        printf("Smth gone wrong!\n");

    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Number is: %d",tmp->broj);
        tmp=tmp->next;

    }
printf("\n");

}


int main(void){

push_onto(15);
push_onto(10);
push_onto(20);
push_onto(12);
//print_elem();
printf("The element removed is : %d",pop());
//print_elem();




return 0;

}
```

This is not my homework, although it looks as such. This is just my attempt at trying to figure out some basic algorithms. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close to "getting it".  I remember it was a bit hard for me to understand structs and pointers at the beginning. But once you "get it" you'll be fine.

It seems you're trying to construct a stack using a simply-linked list.  I'll try to offer some suggestions.

The very first thing that I would modify is your `node` struct.  It is true, you need to keep
track of the head node, but usually you don't need to do it on every node. So we will remove it from your node definition.

```
struct node{ //kreiram stog
    struct node* next;
    int broj;
};
```

Now,  you need to keep track of the head node of your list.  This can be done with a global variable, that I'm going to call head:

```
struct node* head = NULL;
```

I'm initializing it to null because it is empty. A null head pointer will always mean
your stack is empty. **All the code that tries to manipulate the list WILL need to start
with this head node. It is your anchor point.**

Then to the `push_onto()` function

```
void push_onto(int broj){ // dodajem na glavu

    // this bit is fine
    struct node* novi;
    novi=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (novi== NULL)
        printf("Smth is wrong,Jose!\n");

    else {   //I'm adding the bracket, you require it to enclose more than one statement
             //in the else section 
        novi->broj = broj;  // store the number to be pushed on the stack
        novi->next = head;  // link the list, remember head  will
                            // be NULL if the stack was empty
        head = novi;        // make the new node the current head node
   }
}
```

Let's modify the pop() function

```
int pop()// skidam sa stoga
{
    struct node* temp;
    int result;
    // first we will check if the head node is NULL (stack is empty)
    if( head == NULL ) {
        printf("Stack is empty\n"); 
        return -1;
    } else {
       // hold a temporary value to current head pointer, so we can modify the head node  
       // and still refer to it
       temp = head;
       // Head node should now point to the next node on the list (will become NULL when
       // popping the last value. This is what actually "pops" the value from our list
       head = head->next;
       // place in temporary variable the result we are popping. This is so because
       // it's not a good idea to reference the node after we free the memory it is using
       result = temp->broj;  
       // release the memory occupied by the node we're popping
       free(temp);
       return result;
   }
}
```

Finally I'm going to show you how to fix some of the functions that are using your stack

```
void top(){ //koji je element na stogu

    if( head == NULL ) {
       printf("Stack is empty\n");
    } else {
       printf("Trenutni element na stogu je %d",head->broj);
   }
}


void print_elem(){
    struct node* tmp;
    // As you can see, we're initializing tmp to head, since head will always point
    // to the top element of your stack.

    tmp = head;
    if (tmp==NULL) {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return;
    }

    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Number is: %d",tmp->broj);
        tmp=tmp->next;

    }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Hope things are clearer now.  The head node is kept apart as a global variable and as I said before, it is the anchor point to begin manipulating the list.  Feel free to ask me if you're still confused.

=)

Comment: thanks a lot! as you said I am close to getting it, it's just some things that still bug me. I'm one of those that have to "see it" to fully understand it, however strange that sounds for programming. :)) Anyway, thanks!

Comment: LOL, believe it, must of us have to "see it". I started programming in BASIC, and I remember I had intuitively applied the concept of a pointer and indirection, by using an array that itself contained indexes to a second array. When I was introduced to pointers in Pascal, it took me a while to figure out this fact!  Keep it up. Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 3):

```
struct node* temp;
temp=temp->head;
```

You never allocated anything for `temp`. It's just an uninitialized pointer.

It's not clear what you are trying to pop. Your `pop()` function takes no parameters and it accesses no globals. Likewise, I see the same problem with most of your functions there. They are supposed to operate on some sort of stack object, but none of them actually take such an object as a parameter.

Comment: Forget about globals and back up a bit. All your functions are essentially member functions that act on a stack object. So in order to do their job, they need to actually take a stack object as a parameter somewhere. I see that none of them actually do. They seem to be create something local.

Comment: OK, now the solution could be to allocate in each like in push(), or to receive a pointer to the stack..?

Comment: In short, there's too many problems with your code to list without actually rewriting the whole thing. You're probably better off reading about OOP (Object Oriented Programming) first. Then it'll be easier to write this program - which you may discover that you will probably end up having to rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: Actually it is. At least you're attempting to. In C, you don't have classes or member functions, so you have to manually pass the object in as a parameter.